# zsh shell script subscript redirect output to terminal and log file

Tags: pipe, zsh, stdout

I have a situation where I have a master shell script (in zsh) which calls other scripts to facilitate a process.  What I would like is to have the output of my subscripts to be piped to terminal shell and a log file.

Master Script:

```
./run_script1.sh >&1 log1.txt 2>&1
./run_script2.sh >&1 log2.txt 2>&1
```

But when executing I don't get anything on terminal from the output of the other scripts, it only appears in the log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used `zsh`, so I'm not sure whether what you tried makes sense or not.

However, the standard way to send output to both `stdout` and to a separate file is with the [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) Unix command.

So you probably want something like

```
./run_script1.sh 2>&1 | tee log1.txt
./run_script2.sh 2>&1 | tee log2.txt
```